# django-tenant-schemas: Migrate data from shared schema to multi tenant schema

Tags: python, django, django-models, multi-tenant, django-south

How to migrate data from shared schema to multi tenant schema using django-tenant-schemas?

We have a saas and initially didn't use django-tenant-schemas but Shared Database, Shared Schema approach. We now discovered django-tenant-schemas and decided it is the right way to go.

The problem is now how to migrate the data from the single `public` schema to independent tenant schemas.

`django-tenant-schemas` documentation says the following:

> Note: your database should be empty if this is the first time you’re
>   running this command.

In my existing app, I've a tenant table to which all other models have ForeignKey but everything is in the public schema. I use `south` migration. Now I need to migrate all this tenant data to separate schemas. How to do the same?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick on doing this. First you should be aware of psql dump and load commands.

Steps:

1. your previous django app consists a single database with all tables in `public` schema. dump it to a `pgsql` file using `pg_dump` command. lets say `database.pgsql`.
2. write a shell script which first loads this dump to a temporary database, lets say `temp_db`.
3. since the schema it will dump in is public schema, alter the schema name to preferred schema to the one you prefer to be in the tenant-schema implemented database, lets say `tenant_xyz`.
4. again dump, this time the schema `tenant_xyz` to `tenant_xyz.pgsql`.
5. load that `tenant_xyz` schema dump to tenant-schema implemented database, lets say `postgres`.
6. now the tenant_xyz's schema with dump loaded will be available in `postgres` database inside preferred schema.

Script is given below:

```
psql -U postgres -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS temp_db"
psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE temp_db"
psql -U postgres temp_db < database.pgsql
psql -U postgres -d temp_db -c "ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO teanat_xyz"
pg_dump -U postgres -d temp_db -n tenant_xyz > tenant_xyz.pgsql
psql -U postgres -c "DROP DATABASE temp_db"
psql -U postgres -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tenant_xyz CASCADE"
psql -U postgres postgres < tenant_xyz.pgsql
```